# Custom Keyboard event in windows side

Tags: windows

CTRL + C means Copy
CTRL + V means Paste

I want to write my custom keyboard event like above.

As instance,

I have e-mail adress

```
"info@info.com"
```

If ı enter CTRL + W ı want to write my e-mail adress automaticly where ı paste it.

How can ı do it in windows side ?

or I must write code in c# something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many softwares that handle global events in Windows, like [this one](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which is a scripting tool and you can do what you want.

Sharon